# Uploadify cannot read the property 'queueData'

Tags: javascript, uploadify, swfupload

I have no idea what's going on with this one. I have 2 placeholder elements that I replace with uploadify instances. The 2 placeholder html elements are exactly the same, and they are replaced with with the exact same uploadify code (loop through the 2 placeholders with a jquery .each). The only difference is that they have different IDs.

One of them works completely fine, the other one throws the exception 'cannot read property queueData of undefined'. I checked in the uploadify code and this is happening because it can't find the swfupload that should be stored. The relevant code within uploadify is here

```
if (flashInstalled) {
                // Create the swfUpload instance
                window['uploadify_' + settings.id] = new SWFUpload(swfUploadSettings);
                var swfuploadify = window['uploadify_' + settings.id];

                // Add the SWFUpload object to the elements data object
                $this.data('uploadify', swfuploadify);
```

and the part where it's trying to retrieve it from the $this.data

```
// Start uploading files in the queue
    upload : function() {

        var args = arguments;

        this.each(function() {
            // Create a reference to the jQuery DOM object
            var $this        = $(this),
                swfuploadify = $this.data('uploadify');

            // Reset the queue information
            swfuploadify.queueData.averageSpeed  = 0;
            swfuploadify.queueData.uploadSize    = 0;
```

swfuploadify turns up as 'undefined'. I debugged into this as it was happening, and that first line where it set that data definitely happened, but it was undefined by the time the second part happened. I don't understand this at all.

Answer (score 2):

It seems obvious but check that you have flash installed, I just ran across the exact bug on our development machine and that's resolved the issue.

Comment: Omg, after hours of searching online, this was the solution. THANKS!